# Discard string after nth line break in pandas dataframe string column

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with several columns. Looking at one of them, type string, my goal is to discard every character after the 500th line break.

My approach until now: Looping over `n=len(string)`, count `\n` and `split()`. Is there something more elegant and efficient that I could do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you used when you say you counted the "\n", but using the `join()` and the `split()` function is a pretty clean way to do it :

```
a = "a \n b \n c \n d"

"".join(a.split("\n")[0:2])

'a  b '
```

Since you are working with a dataframe you can combine this with a list comprehension to get a neat result :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A" : ["a \n b \n c \n d", "d \n e \n f \n g"]})

df['A'] = ["".join(x.split("\n")[0:2]) for x in df['A']]

     A
0  a  b 
1  d  e
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit more efficient solution, will split only to `m+1` parts -

```
df['A'] = ["".join(x.split("\n")[0:2]) for x in df['A']]
m = 2
df['A'] = ["".join(x.split("\n", m)[:-1]) for x in df['A']]
```

And if we want to leverage pandas string functions -

```
df['A'] = df.A.str.split('\n',m).apply(lambda x: x[:-1]).str.join(" ")
```